# Django - create instance of model with user_id

Tags: python, sql, django

I have two models, `player` and `game`. The model `player` is an extended Django Auth User Model. I am trying to create an instance of game with the User ID and not the player ID which is automatically created. Is it possible to do that in a single query? Django Version: 1.11.

```
new_game = Game(active=False,
                        ### user_id=request.user.id,
                        display_every=display_every,
                        lead_to_win=lead_to_win,
                        p1_coins=num_of_coins,
                        p2_coins=num_of_coins,
                        created=django.utils.timezone.now())

new_game.save()
```

This command creates the instance. Its the user_id which is not working and it only works with player_id which I have to fetch with another query. I have commented it to highlight the line.

```
class Game(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    over = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    winner = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
    player1 = models.OneToOneField(Player, related_name='player1')
    player2 = models.OneToOneField(Player, related_name='player2', null=True)
    p1_coins = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    p2_coins = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    array = models.TextField(default=json.dumps([(None, None) for x in range(100)]))
    round_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    display_every = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    lead_to_win = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)


class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='/static/images/anon.jpg', upload_to='static/images/profile-pics/', null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    matches = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    wins = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    losses = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    win_string = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
```

Also, I have both the models in different apps if it matters.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Where is relation between `Game` and `User`? I don't see it.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar There is no relation between them. They are connected through the Model `Player`.

Comment: I do not see the Player Model extending Django Auth User Model.   The Player model should inherit AbstarctUser. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: How you want to get `user_id` from `Game` instance? `game.player1.user.id`? Will it store in db or should get from `player1/player2`?

Comment: @tellk The link you have posted is for substituting a custom user model. I am referring to the topic above that.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar It should get from player1 and player2.

Comment: @TheRandomGuy ok. And what will be if there are different? For example, `game.player1.user.id = 1`, but `game.player2.user.id = 2`. What will return `game.user_id`?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar There is no such thing as game.user_id. I just wrote it. I want it to return that.

Comment: @TheRandomGuy ok. you can add `@property
    def user_id(self):
        return self.player1.user.id` to your `Game` class. To set `user_id` you should set `Player` instance with `User` to `Game`. Example, `player = Player(user=user_instance_with_id, other fields...) game = Game(player1=player) print game.user_id`